# Will Process.WaitForInputIdle Method serve my purpose of waiting for process to start?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

We have an exe application (VB6). This app is called by our .NET dll assembly (using `Process.Start`) which passes username and password to the vb6 app as arguments.
The VB6 app has code which looks for windows messages only after login code is executed.

It works well if I do :-

**CASE1:**

```
Process.Start("file.exe", arguments);
Thread.Sleep(1000); //if I comment this line then the msg is never caught by the vb6 app
SendAWindowsMsg("hello");
```

**CASE2:**

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"file.exe",
        Arguments = arguments
    }
};
process.Start();
process.WaitForInputIdle();
SendAWindowsMsg("hello");
```

My question is: Will case 1 or case 2 be the better approach? What is the meaning of `WaitForInputIdle` (what's the input and idle thing?)?

Comment: Only you can answer the question of if it "serves your purpose." Read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2(v=vs.110).aspx) and then give it a try to see if it does what you want for the specific process you are launching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Case 1** - assumes the process finished loading in 1 second.
- **Case 2** - waits for the process to finish loading [*definitely the way to go*].

The purpose of the `WaitForInputIdle` function is for a process to determine whether another process (which is recently launched) has reached **a state where it is okay to send that process messages**.

Basically `WaitForInputIdle` it's asking if the process finished loading.

Comment: What do you mean by "a state where it is okay to send that process messages"? The app that launches has a parent window and child window which is launched from parent window code.. So will the calling process wait until this child window is loaded?

Comment: What do you mean by process has finished loading...? Suppose there is a login form for the application and the child form is called after you enter credentials, then at which point will the wait have finished? at point of display of login form? or at point after the credentials are validated and child form is loaded?

Comment: By *finished loading* i mean *finish loading **resources** needed to start the process* (libraries and variables). So `WaitForInputIdle` will trigger when your login form will popup, not after you validate the credentials.

Comment: What if I am passing credentials by arguments.. Then, the child form code will be immediately called.. and the calling process will wait for the called application to load GUI of the child form?

Comment: In this scenario, yes it will wait for the GUI to load.